# Change class attribute of td by onmouseover

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I'm constructing a table. And I need a `<td>` of table change it's attribute `class` to `someattribute` till mouse over.

How should it be?

Code:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++)
{
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('id',i)
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 1; j <=15; j++)
    {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('id',j);
        // Here:
        td.OnMouseOver = new function() 
        {
            td.setAttribute("class","new");
        };
        tr.appendChild(td);
    };
};

document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(table);
```

Comment: `td.onmouseover = function() {`

Comment: This is the kind of thing that jQuery eats for breakfast.

Comment: you should not create functions inside loops, it will just confuse you. like here `td.setAttribute("class","new");` will only apply to the last `td` created

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close.

Use the keyword `this` in your `onmouseover` function, instead of `td`, which is not accessible to your function. Also, you do not need to use the keyword `new` to define a function.

```
    td.onmouseover = function () {
        this.setAttribute("class", "new");
    };
```

Code:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('id', i)
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('id', j);
        td.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        td.onmouseover = function () {
            this.setAttribute("class", "new");
        };
        tr.appendChild(td);
    };
};

document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(table);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/VnkHB/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to use jQuery:

```
$('table td').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('new');
});
```

This would add the class `new` to any `<td>` element in any `<table>` on the `mouseover` event.

Answer (score 0):

without jQuery:

```
function mouseover() {
    this.setAttribute("class", "new");
    return true;
}

var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr, td;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.setAttribute('id', 'td'+i);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        for (var j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.setAttribute('id', 'tr'+j);
            // Here:
            td.onmouseover = mouseover;
            td.innerText = "..";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
}

document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(table);
```

function is moved to outside the loop, ids are prefixed to avoid collision

with jQuery:

```
function mouseover() {
    this.setAttribute("class", "new");
    return true;
}

function nNewElements(tag, idPrefix, n) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result.
        push($("<" + tag + ">").
        attr("id", idPrefix + i)[0]);
    }
    return $(result);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").
    html('').
    append('<table>');

    nNewElements("tr", "row", 10).
    appendTo("table").
    each(function () {
        nNewElements("td", "data", 15).
        mouseover(mouseover).
        text("..").
        appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```